# How to Handle Overflow with jsPDF and html2canvas?

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

```
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

export function pdfDownload(downloadFileName: string) {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".paper"); // 다운받을 div의 className을 입력
    
    elements.forEach((element, index) => {
      const htmlElement = element as HTMLElement; // 형변환을 통해 HTMLElement로 지정
      html2canvas(htmlElement).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
        const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm");
        const imgWidth = 210;
        const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
        const pageHeight = 295;
        let heightLeft = imgHeight;
        let position = 0;
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, 10, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
          position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
          pdf.addPage();
          pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }
        pdf.save(`${downloadFileName}-${index + 1}.pdf`);
      });
    });
}
```

When the horizontal size is reduced, causing the UI to overflow and hide behind a horizontal scroll, the downloaded PDF also gets cut off. Additionally, when the data extends downwards, creating a long page, in order to maintain an A4-shaped PDF, the data gets truncated in the middle.

How to solve it?

Resizing CSS for a responsive layout was challenging. Confining data neatly within an A4 format proved to be difficult.